# Reverting commit on bitbucket cloud GUI

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-revert

Is there a way to revert a commit on the bitbucket cloud GUI? I want to revert the last commit on a branch.

Comment: Short answer is no. Side questions/remarks: 1) this is trivial in a local repo, and 2) be sure `git revert` is what you need here. If the branch isn't shared, a reset might be a better course of action. Lastly, 3) Is it a merge commit you want to revert?

Comment: @RomainValeri It's not a merge commit. Could you please provide some hints on why the reset is a better option if the branch is not shared? Is it because it removes the history and the revert logs won't appear in the `git log` command output?

Comment: Yes, you probably don't need two consecutive commits canceling out each other, I guess. But on a shared branch, depending on the number of people interacting with the repo, it might be much more of an hassle to rewrite history and cause some to be out of sync with the new history, so two "useless" commits are a very small nuisance comparatively.